# Admob interstitials fail using AsyncTask

Tags: android, firebase, admob, ads

I'm trying to load Admob interstitial ads through an async task as follows:

```
private class AdLoaderTask extends AsyncTask<InterstitialAd, Integer, InterstitialAd> {

    InterstitialAd mLocalInterstitialAd;

    protected InterstitialAd doInBackground(InterstitialAd... ads) {
          mLocalInterstitialAd = ads[0];
        AdRequest.Builder builder = new AdRequest.Builder();
        if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
              builder.addTestDevice("XXXX");
        }
          AdRequest adRequest = builder.build();
        mLocalInterstitialAd.loadAd(adRequest);
        return mLocalInterstitialAd;
    }
    protected void onPostExecute(Long result) {
        if (mLocalInterstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
            setLoadedInterstitialAd(mLocalInterstitialAd);
        } else {
            loadInterstitialAd(mLocalInterstitialAd);
        }
    }

}
```

I'm getting this exception:

```
07-21 11:11:32.898 E/AndroidRuntime(14359): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
07-21 11:11:32.898 E/AndroidRuntime(14359):     at android.os.Handler.<init>(Handler.java:200)
07-21 11:11:32.898 E/AndroidRuntime(14359):     at android.os.Handler.<init>(Handler.java:114)
07-21 11:11:32.898 E/AndroidRuntime(14359):     at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.prefetch.b.<init>(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesA:37)
07-21 11:11:32.898 E/AndroidRuntime(14359):     at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.prefetch.b.<init>(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesA:31)
07-21 11:11:32.898 E/AndroidRuntime(14359):     at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.c.<init>(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesA:106)
```

Does this mean ads can't be loaded via AsyncTask, even though the task itself is executed from the UI thread?

How to get around this? The `MobileAds.initialize, setAdUnitId` *do* seem to work in an AsyncTask. Am I missing something? Ads load fine when not using AsyncTask. Possible to load through a `Service` ?

Comment: Obviously I am missing something as just down-voted...

Comment: I've not done anything with AdMob, but I would imagine it already does everything it can asynchronously. Are you sure you need to put that in an `AsyncTask`?

Comment: I'm sure now you shouldn't put it in an AsyncTask...
ad.loadAd(adRequest) starts async loading by admob, but running that command takes about 0.5 sec on the UI thread on an Xperia Z1, I guess you have to live with that (?).
Getting started:  https://firebase.google.com/docs/admob/android/interstitial
Sample: https://github.com/googleads/googleads-mobile-android-examples/tree/master/admob/InterstitialExample

Answer (score 0):

Don't try and use `AsyncTask`; admob loads ads asynchronously and includes an `AdListener` class which you can extend to receive call backs for `onAdLoaded()`,`onAdFailedToLoad()` etc See https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/ads/package-summary